# Show result after button action to table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

```
var monthsOfNonWorking = ["1. mēnesis","2. mēnesis","3. mēnesis","4. mēnesis","5. mēnesis","6. mēnesis","7. mēnesis","8. mēnesis","9. mēnesis",]        

@IBAction func nonWorkingAllowanceCalculate(_ sender: Any) {

    var firstThreeMonths :Double
    var secondThreeMonths :Double
    var LastThreeMonths :Double

    let bezdarbienieka_alga = Double(bezd_alga.text!)


    if (staza_masiva_lasisana == 0) {

        firstThreeMonths = Double(bezdarbienieka_alga! / 2)

        secondThreeMonths = Double(firstThreeMonths / 2)

        LastThreeMonths = Double(bezdarbienieka_alga! / 1.6 - secondThreeMonths) }}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MonthTableViewCell

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: cell.nonWorkingAllowance?.text = String()

    }

    cell.monthLabel?.text = monthsOfNonWorking[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

How to show result on table view cell after calculation with button action?
For example, I want to show data `firstThreeMonths` on `tableViewCell`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `tableView.reloadData()` in the end of the button action.

```
@IBAction func nonWorkingAllowanceCalculate(_ sender: Any) {

var firstThreeMonths :Double
var secondThreeMonths :Double
var LastThreeMonths :Double

let bezdarbienieka_alga = Double(bezd_alga.text!)


if (staza_masiva_lasisana == 0) {

    firstThreeMonths = Double(bezdarbienieka_alga! / 2)

    secondThreeMonths = Double(firstThreeMonths / 2)

    LastThreeMonths = Double(bezdarbienieka_alga! / 1.6 - secondThreeMonths)
 }

 tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe this question is not so hard, but I'm studying. Thank you.

Comment: @user3465573 if the answer solves your issue, please don't forget to accept it (green tick).